# JExcelAPI has deep copy feature using copyTo(col,row) method. Nothing find in Apache POI

Tags: apache-poi, jxl, jexcelapi

JExcelAPI (jxl) has a deep copy feature  using WritableCell.copyTo(int col, int row) method.

I couldn't find anything like this in Apache POI .

I need to copy the formula cells and formula should change relative way in the new cell using Apache POI.

Your help would be appreciated greatly.

Thanks
Siva